# Нужна ли запятая перед «и» в вопросительном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

*Такая уж ли она идеальная, образцовая эта смерть, **и** за что же все-таки дают ордена?*

В одном предложении два самостоятельных вопроса. Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1):

***Такая уж ли она идеальная, образцовая эта смерть, и за что же все-таки дают ордена?***

Можно предположить, что запятая **нужна**, хотя союз И соединяет два вопросительных предложения.

**ПАС под ред Лопатина** http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо запятая не ставится в следующих случаях:

5. если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей **здесь оказывается интонация,** а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: *Где будет собрание и кто его председатель?* — общая вопросительная интонация;

Но в нашем случае нет объединяющей общей вопросительной интонации, так как в первом предложении есть **однородные члены** с перечислительной интонацией.

Судя по примерам, это правило следует применять для простых нераспространенных предложений, которые можно произнести **в одну фонетическую фразу**, обозначив вопросительную интонацию (повышение голоса) в конце предложения.

Comment: СПАСИБО, Dear Sharon! ПРИЗНАТЕЛЬНА за подробные разъяснения.Интуитивно ощущала наличие запятой, не могла объяснить. Просмотрела множество правил, но... увы! Очень признательна! С Новым годом! Счастья и благополучия!

Answer (score 1):

> *Такая уж ли **она** идеальная, **образцовая эта смерть**, и за что же все-таки дают ордена?*

Запятыми здесь обособлено **распространённое приложение.**

**Из ПАС под ред. Лопатина:**

> **§ 61.** Распространенные приложения, стоящие после определяемого слова —
> существительного или местоимения, а также отделенные от них другими
> членами предложения или относящиеся к отсутствующему члену
> предложения, обособляются запятыми: <…> ***Они** очень разные, **эти
> строки**, они противостоят друг другу* (Зал.); ***Он** думал всю эту
> ночь, **Вершинин-старший*** (Зал.); ***Он** был горек и духовит,
> **этот крылатый, степной, восточный ветер*** (Шол.)…

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Answer (score 0):

**Нужна**, но не потому, что два самостоятельных вопроса, а потому, что выражение "образцовая эта смерть" носит вставной, пояснительный характер.
Если бы предложение звучало так: *"Образцовая смерть — такая уж ли она идеальная и за что же все-таки дают ордена?"* — то запятой бы не требовалось, поскольку в вопросительных ССП она между частями не ставится (см. [Розенталь, Пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133), § 30.3).

Comment: Уважаемый Nektoid! Благодарю за пояснение и подтверждение запятой! Да еще и с указанием на Розенталя!  Есть, о чем помыслить!  С Новым годом и наилучшими пожеланиями!